# Substitution for Weierstrass Substitution

Tags: calculus

I recently learnt about the Weierstrass Substitution for integrals of the form: $$\frac{d}{a \sin x+b \cos x}$$ You substitute $\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ as $t$, and proceed to algebraically manipulate the equation to get partial fractions. Why does this not work with $\tan x$ instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The relation of the trigonometric functions with $t=\tan(x)$ are
$$ \cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{1+t^2},\quad \sin^2(x) = \frac{t^2}{1+t^2},\quad dx=\frac{1}{1+t^2} dt. $$
Hence, for simple linear $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, you're going to introduce annoying square roots, without even considering the choice of roots signs. One way to avoid this is to rewrite the squared sine and cosine as another linear trigonometric function, thanks to
$$\cos(2x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x) = 2\cos^2(x) -1.$$
Here is the reason why it is indeed natural to use half-angle substitution, understandable sacrifice in order to obtain rational functions without square roots.

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $\tan x$ *does* work, but requires *more* work to get to the same end result.

---

We have the identity

$$\tan x=\dfrac{2\tan\frac x2}{1-\tan^2\frac x2} \implies \tan x\tan\dfrac x2+1= \sqrt{1+\tan^2x}$$

which for $\left(\tan x,\tan\dfrac x2\right)\to(t,u)$ matches the pattern for the second class of [Euler substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#Euler%27s_second_substitution). In other words, after replacing $t=\tan x$, let
$$u=\frac{\sqrt{1+t^2}-1}t \implies t = \frac{2u}{1-u^2}$$
to end up with
$$\int \frac{dx}{a\sin x+b\cos x} = \int \frac{dt}{(at+b) \sqrt{1+t^2}} = \int \frac{2\left\lvert u^2-1\right\rvert}{\left(u^2-1\right) \left(bu^2-2au-b\right)} \, du$$

Due to our choice in substitution, we restrict the domain to

$$x\in\left(-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right) \implies t\in(-\infty,\infty) \implies u\in(-1,1)$$

so that $\dfrac{\left\lvert u^2-1\right\rvert}{u^2-1}=-1$.

---

On the other hand, the half-angle substitution more immediately yields

$$\int \frac{dx}{a\sin x+b\cos x} \stackrel{v=\tan\tfrac x2}= \int \frac2{-bv^2+2av+b}\,dv$$

thanks to the algebra of the equivalent trig expressions listed in the other answer.